# Sharing website in Books (= printing as pdf) does not work anymore in Safari, crashing the website. How to save a pdf of the website to Books?

Tags: iphone, pdf, books, mobile-safari

On my iPhone 7, roughly till 2021, I used to print Safari websites that I wanted to save as a whole pdf by just sharing it with Books. I stopped doing so after switching to another browser, but now, I tried it again in Safari, and the website crashes as soon as I share the website with the Books app. I checked the pdfs in the Books app, but the crash seems to stop the printout, no new pdf printouts are in there after a few tests.

When I try the same thing with Firefox, it shows "Creating PDF. Preparing...", closes the popup window and does not crash the website, but it also does not reach the point of saving the pdf in the Books app.

Was this saving as pdf in the Books app stopped entirely by Apple? It would not be astonishing, since there was no built-in way to move those Books pdfs to the computer, see [iPhone: bulk move ALL voice memos + ALL pdfs generated from Safari page prints (pdf-exports using "Books") to pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62434692/iphone-bulk-move-all-voice-memos-all-pdfs-generated-from-safari-page-prints/62701384#62701384). I also saw that there is another way of printing pdfs of a website, with:

- share
- --> print
- --> zoom in the preview
- --> share that zoomed pdf
- --> choose any app to save it.

But these are many more steps than just to share it on the phone, in Books, as I could do it before. How can I revive this?

*Mind that I do recommend saving websites as pdf to Books, even if it worked, since saving to Books saves it only on the phone, and I had to buy a program that can restore items from the iPhone backup only to get those pdfs, see above. You cannot just get them with iTunes. For me, this is still fine, since I already have that backup-restore program.*

Comment: Doesn't Share->Options->Send As->PDF meet your needs?

Comment: @AivarPaalberg good hint. I changed from "Automatic" to "PDF". Then I chose the menu point "Save to Files", but it crahed the website, I had to wait for a minute, then Safari crashed, and when I loaded it again, the website reloaded. Tried the same with the menu point "OneDrive", which crashed while the menu zoomed out, right before it would normally switch to the OneDrive menu to let me choose a folder.

Comment: Can’t replicate described scenario. Maybe it’s website? I saved Wikipedia as pdf to Files with no problems whatsoever. Same with sharing to e-mail and via AirDrop

Comment: @AivarPaalberg Good news then. It must be a problem of my phone. My Firefox also crashes as well as soon as a pdf gets sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Full-page screenshot

First, take a screenshot of any part of the page you want to save.

When the screenshot thumbnail appears at the bottom-left-corner of your screen, click on it. An screenshot editing menu will be displayed. At the top-middle of your screen, there is an option that is normally set to "Screen", click the "**Full-page**" button right next to it to have the whole page saved.

This should bring up the entire page as a PDF-like document (which can be annotated). Now, click on the "**Save**" button and select the location in Files where you would like to save it. A PDF of the page will be saved in Files.

To open the PDF in Books; go to the Files app, long press the PDF you just saved until an action menu comes up and click "Share". Then select "Books" from the suggested apps.

If it still crashes, reboot and try again.

Comment: I did not know about taking a full screen screenshot like this. And then to save it as PDF even. These both together are already what I need, since I do not have to save it to Books, that was just the way it worked before (with the caveat that you could not get those files to your computer without a program you had to buy, see the link in the question). Thus, in future, I can use this trick to save a PDF to Files, and that in any browser, not just in Safari.